# Issues when build multhreaded wasm as a module

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

We are building emscr app that uses pthreads as a module.
Here are  the linker options:

> -sWASM=1 -sINITIAL_MEMORY=134217728 -sMAX_WEBGL_VERSION=2  -sUSE_GLFW=3 -sFULL_ES3 -sEXIT_RUNTIME -sASYNCIFY  -lembind -sEXPORT_ES6=1 -sUSE_ES6_IMPORT_META=1 -sMODULARIZE=1 -sEXPORT_NAME=FooModule -sENVIRONMENT=web,worker -sUSE_PTHREADS=1 -sPTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=4  -sOFFSCREENCANVAS_SUPPORT=1 -sOFFSCREEN_FRAMEBUFFER -pthread -sSHARED_MEMORY

When running this build we start getting all sorts of run time errors on the JS side of things.It is important to note that building the app with all the commands listed above except those that are responsible for building the module works fine. Once we modularize the wasm it seems to be failing loading the worker.
Here is the error message we are getting from the browser:

[image]

Also this:

[image]

When examining the generated .js file we see that is can be related to the fact that  `allocateUnusedWorker()` function needs to specify the type: module ,smth like this:

```
 new Worker(new URL("FooWEB.worker.js", import.meta.url), {
          type: "module",
        })
```

Instead, it does this:

```
new Worker(new URL("FooWEB.worker.js", import.meta.url))
```

Additionally,`Module["canvas"]` seems to be undefined.

`Module["PThread"].receiveObjectTransfer(e.data);` - this doesn't seem to be called,which causes canvas not to initialize.

As result, web worker never receives a message with "run", which should call `Module["PThread"].receiveObjectTransfer(e.data);`
Then  `receiveObjectTransfer` in `FooWEB.js`, which seems responsible for assigning

```
Module["canvas"] = GL.offscreenCanvases[data.moduleCanvasId].offscreenCanvas;           
Module["canvas"].id = data.moduleCanvasId;
```

is never called, which leads to this:

`___pthread_create_js` does not find `Module["canvas"]` and it throws

```
  err(
       'pthread_create: could not find canvas with ID "' +
        name +
        '" to transfer to thread!'
     );
```

Am I missing something in the build configuration?

Answer (score 0):

These options:

```
-sEXPORT_ES6=1 -sUSE_ES6_IMPORT_META=1 -sMODULARIZE=1
```

are used to generate an ESM module that is going to be bundled. Are you using a bundler? If you are not using a bundler, do not generate an ESM module and leave emscripten do its work - this is something that it does very well. If you are using a bundler, it is your bundler that should take care of the `import.meta` and transpile the worker.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this? What is bundler? Also " leave emscripten do its work" - what do you mean? What flags should I remove in this case? All 3?

Comment: If you are not using a bundler, you should remove all three options, add the output js directly to `<scripts>` in the web page and access it via `window`.